# Swift NSKeyedArchiver: Do custom members of an NSCoding-conformant class need to conform to NSCoding as well?

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

Say I have this Swift class:

```
class Foo: NSObject, NSCoding
{
    var stringMember: String
    var intMember: Int
    var customObjectMember: CustomObject
    //conforms with encode and required init...
}
```

I know that "Foo" has to conform to NSCoding so I can archive it. Does the member "customObject" also have to conform to NSCoding/NSObject or can it be a regular Swift class?

Comment: It has to be conformed to NSCoding, if you want to be able to archive the object or else you would receive exception that your customObjectMember is not NSCoding compliant.

Comment: Okay, that's what I figured. I've just tested it out and everything appears to work correctly as long as everything conforms to NSCoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "yes". Custom object members must also conform to NSCoding.